# "Warning: We detected the use of uwsgi with disabled threads" when using Sentry/Raven with Django and PythonAnywhere

Tags: django, uwsgi, pythonanywhere, sentry, raven

Using Django with Sentry/Raven, I am frequently getting the following error :

`/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven/utils/compat.py:216: Warning: We detected the use of uwsgi with disabled threads. This will cause issues with the transport you are trying to use. Please enable threading for uwsgi. (Enable the "enable-threads" flag).`

So, ironically, it seems the error is coming from raven itself.

It looks like I need to enable threading for uwsgi. However, to my knowledge, PythonAnywhere does not support threading (is this right ?).

How can I prevent these errors from showing up ? Are they causing anything damaging apart from these reports ? They don't seem to be affecting the user experience at all.

Note : I found [this thread](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/732) on the Sentry github that seems to reference the same issue, but I'm not sure how to go from here.

Comment: "It looks like I need to enable threading for uwsgi. However, to my knowledge, PythonAnywhere does not support threading (is this right ?)." -- that's correct for website code, yes.  PythonAnywhere supports threading in consoles and in scheduled tasks, but not in websites.

Comment: Since Python Anywhere does not support threads, you need to use the sync transport: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/transports/#sync

Answer (score 3):

`enable-threads` allow sentry raven to send messages in a thread and not block your application. So enabling it should be recommended.

[Relevant documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/advanced/#a-note-on-uwsgi)